# How to type SubmitEvent so that event.target.children is known?

Tags: typescript

I have the following form:

```
<form id="search" method="post">
<input type="text" name="query" id="search-field"/>
</form>
```

And I want to attach a submit event listener in TypeScript:

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("submit", (event: SubmitEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.children.query.value);
    });
```

However typescript gives me the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

20    console.log(event.target.children.query.value);
```

How can I tell TypeScript that the target of the submit event is a form, which has a valid `children.query` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the event can happen on any HTML element it is tricky for TS to figure out on which element the event was triggered. You can help it by using a type assertion, it is not fancy and it feels "forced" but it works if you know that your event will be triggered only on a given HTML element.

With this strategy your code would be something like (after checking types I changed a little bit since the types prompted me to this usage)

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("submit", (event: SubmitEvent) => {
    const form = event.target as HTMLFormElement;
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log((form.children.namedItem("search-field") as HTMLInputElement).value);
});
```

Note that the return value of `namedItem` is of type `Element` which is too generic, that's why I had to cast it to `HTMLInputElement` that in this case contains a **value**